# Use my Android keyboard App as default Keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad, android-input-method, android-inputtype

I've made a sample android soft keyboard. I want it to use across all applications (hangout, whatsapp etc). What are the possible ways to do it? ( below are the options I'm thinking of )

1. To run this as service and to detect if android softkeyboard is invoked and disable that and run my softkeyboard ( i don't want this).
2. I want it to be shown in Settings> Language and Input > Keyboard .
   Where I can select the keyboard .(Preferred method). Ssome of my friends liked my new keyboard and want to use it. So I think this will be better option.

I'm stuck now.Any suggestions on how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Checkout how the [InputMethodLatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/) works.

Comment: So what's not working? Doesn't your keyboard appear in the list of input methods (as per option 2)? Does your keyboard extend [`InputMethodService`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To run this as service and to detect if android softkeyboard is invoked and disable that and run my softkeyboard ( i don't want this).

Moreover, that is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

> I want it to be shown in Settings> Language and Input > Keyboard

If you implemented an input method editor following [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html), it should already be there.